# Python: pick elements with different indexes and store them in a new Dataframe column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to compute the following operation, described in a loop:

```
for ii in range(0,len(df['Avg'])):
    if ii==0:
        df['Return'][ii]=0
    else:
        df['Return'][ii] = (df['Avg'][ii])/(df['Avg'][ii-1])-1
```

I want to use 'present' and 'previous' element from 'Avg' column to make that operation, but I'm getting this error:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   df['Return'][ii]=0 C:/Users/julio/Desktop/Python Scripts/Euclid
>   Capital Scripts/DukasCopy/duka_test:34: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A
>   value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   df['Return'][ii] = (df['Avg'][ii])/(df['Avg'][ii-1])-1

Is there another way to achieve what I want and store those values in the 'Return' column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html):

```
df.loc[:, 'Return'] = df['Avg'].pct_change()
```

Or, to start off with a leading zero instead of an NaN, chain `.fillna`:

```
df.loc[:, 'Return'] = df['Avg'].pct_change().fillna(0.)
```

As for the warning you're seeing, there's a lot of info out there about what's happening here already:

- [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)
- [Understanding SettingwithCopyWarning in pandas](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/)
- [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

In your case, using `df['Return'][ii]` is what leads to this.  You are using chained indexing where it would be safer to use `.loc` or `.iloc`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Avg' : np.random.rand(10) + 1},
                  index=pd.date_range('2017-02', periods=10))
df.loc[:, 'Return'] = df['Avg'].pct_change().fillna(0.)
print(df)
                Avg   Return
2017-02-01  1.86389  0.00000
2017-02-02  1.19992 -0.35623
2017-02-03  1.08414 -0.09649
2017-02-04  1.17281  0.08179
2017-02-05  1.30422  0.11204
2017-02-06  1.59484  0.22284
2017-02-07  1.63399  0.02455
2017-02-08  1.99155  0.21883
2017-02-09  1.54733 -0.22305
2017-02-10  1.50584 -0.02682
```